# using AMD to return two objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, amd

I am using requireJS as so

```
require({
    paths: {
        'dependency': 'dependency_path',
        ...
    }
}, ['main.js'], function(App) {
    App.functionA();
    App.functionB();
});
```

and in `main.js`

```
define(['dependency','...'],function() {
            function functionA(){...}
            function functionB(){...}
return {
functionA : functionA,
functionB : functionB
}
```

The problem is that, if the last returns either the single value `functionA` or `functionB`, I get no error, but if I add both functions as return values, `functionB` doesn't trigger anything. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

For your entry point, you should use `requirejs(...` instead of `require(...`. The latter is more for requiring code at runtime. It looks like you are using the `requirejs` syntax with your `require` statement. I think the second argument to `require` is a function.

See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Also you shouldn't use the '.js' extension in your require statement.  And you should also put a path. So instead of

```
}, ['main.js'], function(App) {
```

use

```
}, ['./main'], function(App) {
```

Comment: in fact I have a path `js/vendor/upload/main.js`, if I delete `vendor/upload/main` nothing works

Comment: @user1611830 The path statement is relative to the file where the entry point is. Unless I know what the paths of both files are, I can't give you the exact references you should use, but I really think the big problem you have is that you are using `require` instead of `requirejs`. But you should not use the extension See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths